# Beginner GWAS topic: virtual box command line can't find .ped file?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am new to GWAS analysis and I've been trying to run the PLINK tutorial sample datasets (hapmap 80K loci) on gPLINK to do some exclusions. I am currently working on a Mac OSX 10.10. I've applied the threshold settings (high missing rate, low MAF etc.) to my file "hapmap1.ped" and prepared to execute the command through gPLINK, however it keeps giving me the error prompt "can not execute command locally".

Is there something wrong with my library or directory settings?

Answer (score 0):

gPlink runs in two modes a remote mode and a local one. It seems you are running the local one. Please check if you are specifying the correct path where PLINK is installed when cofiguring gPlink. For more details refer to [gPlink configuration](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/gplink_tutorial/p1.html)